# Merge tables with unequal number of columns without returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one is called `original_table` and the other is `table_with_additional_column`.

`table_with_additional_column` is a subset of `original_table` but with an additional column called `sequenceNr`. I want to merge the two tables such that I can get all rows from `original_table` with `sequenceNr` set to NULL where the rest of the column values don´t match the ones in `table_with_additional_column`. I would like to replace the rows in `original_table` instead of just inserting the rows from `table_with_additional_column`

Here´s an example:

`original_table`

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ggg |
| ccc | ddd | hhh |
| eee | fff | iii |

`table_with_additional_column`

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | sequencenr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ggg | 1 |
| ccc | ddd | hhh | 2 |

What I want as result of merge:

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | sequencenr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ggg | 1 |
| ccc | ddd | hhh | 2 |
| eee | fff | iii | NULL |

Here´s my query so far:

```
SELECT 
  column_1, column_2, column_3, sequenceNr

FROM (
    SELECT 
        table_A.*, 
        table_B.sequenceNr
    FROM table_A, table_B
) AS table_with_additional_column

RIGHT JOIN original_table ON original_table.column_1 = table_with_additional_column.column_1
AND original_table.column_2 = table_with_additional_column.column_2 
AND original_table.column_3 = table_with_additional_column.column_3
```

I would appreciate some help with the SQL query regarding how to merge the two tables. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left join` for this:

```
select ot.*, twac.sequencenr
from original_table ot left join
     table_with_additional_column twac
     on ot.col1 = twac.col1 and
        ot.col2 = twac.col2 and
        ot.col3 = twac.col3;
```

Your description pretty much explains exactly what `left join` does.